# Using vim editor to create a Scala script within REPL

Tags: scala, scala-repl

Version of Scala I am using is Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121) and the Jline Library present is 2.14.3 .

This could sound silly but I am trying to figure out the problem when trying to create a scala file using editor cmd line vi or vim during the Scala REPL mode its throwing error. Below is my error .. Could you please let me know if there is any specific Scala Terminal console that I am suppose to use or am I doing something wrong ?

```
scala> vi test1.scala
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
vi test1.scala
```

I am able to do a VI and VIM as well in my system without the SCALA REPL mode but when I am in REPL I am not able to create a scala script file and execute it . What could be wrong ? Is there any settings that needs to be enabled for this ?

Answer (score 1):

For saving your REPL history, use `:save file`.

There is limited support for using an external editor. The result of the edit is run immediately. After a reset, only the edited lines are in session history, so save will save only those lines.

```
$ EDITOR=gedit scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val x = 42
x: Int = 42

scala> println(x)
42

scala> :edit -2
+val x = 17
+println(x)
17
x: Int = 17

scala> :hi 3
1896  val x = 17
1897  println(x)
1898  :hi 3

scala> :reset
Resetting interpreter state.
Forgetting this session history:

val x = 42
println(x)
val x = 17
println(x)


Forgetting all expression results and named terms: $intp, x

scala> :ed 1896+2
+val x = 5
+println(x)
5
x: Int = 5

scala> :save sc.sc

scala> :load sc.sc
Loading sc.sc...
x: Int = 5
5
```